# Can't find specific gem on my mac

Tags: ruby, macos, bundler

I have a Mac which I use for developing Ruby on Rails applications. I use Bundler for my gems and I installed the gem Comma with Bundler. But I can't find the physical Comma files. I have looked in "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/" and there are a lot of ruby gems stored, but not Comma. Where should I find the Comma files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the `gem env` command you should see all paths where your gems are installed, under the GEM PATHS label

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you can also use `gem which <gem name>`. This is great for stuff like, say `mvim $(gem which comma)`, or the equivalent for `mate`, `emacs`, etc. I've even got a mapping in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :exe "e " . system("gem which ")<Left><Left>
```

so I can browse gem files quickly (add in `escape(..., ' ')` if necessary).